# JQuery mouse hover over table row, get text of that table row?

Tags: jquery

Just like the title states. How can I get the text of the table row that the mouse is currently hovered over?

I'm using this to show a thumbnail of the image that the user is hovering over (the table shows a list of image filenames stored in a database).

Comment: The answer is also in your title.  Add an event handler for `hover` to the table row.  https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: try jquery plugin `tooltipster`

Comment: try jquery plugin `tooltipster`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

**html**

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>this is msg 1</td>
            <td>werwer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>this is msg 2</td>
            <td>werwer</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').mouseover(function(){
        var valueOfTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
        alert(valueOfTd); // Do here what you want with the value.
    });
});
</script>
```